# mule log files into DB

Tags: log4j, mule, mule-flow

In mule CE version 3.3.0, I have a mule project, and the URL for calling it is `http://localhost:8086/mule?msg=Hello-World!!!`.

Every time that I call it, in a log file in mule server that it has as a default some lines added as a log.

Now I want to change type of logs in mule? I want to instead the file that mule create it for logs, as a default mule create a table into Database and save important info into it.

Actually I want to have a table log for my projects, and in this table I want to have customers' information such as IP and ...

Is it possible?
How can I do it?

Comment: Have you looked at the JDBCAppender for log4j?

Comment: @DavidDossot it means, I use log4j in mule for adding log info into Database?

Comment: @DavidDossot, How can I use log4j in mule?

Comment: See: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configuring+Logging

Comment: I tried this recently and got it working. It's complex and it involves working with JDBCAppender, a Java file in your mule app which makes the Connection & Pooling.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Log4j database appender to insert Mule ESB logs into database. Below code snippet is used to do the same.

```
<appender name="DB" class="org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender">
   <param name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/DBNAME"/>
   <param name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
   <param name="user" value="user_id"/>
   <param name="password" value="password"/>
   <param name="sql" value="INSERT INTO LOGS VALUES('%level','%message','%X{muleMessage}','%X{payload}')"/>

   <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="log4j.rootLogger" additivity="false">
   <level value="DEBUG"/>
   <appender-ref ref="DB"/>
</logger>
```